# django-sentry not recording warnings, errors, etc

Tags: django, logging, sentry

I just installed django-sentry, and it catches exceptions just fine. However calls to logger.warning and logger.error are not being saved to Sentry for some reason.

Sentry implementation:

```
import logging
from sentry.client.handlers import SentryHandler

logger = logging.getLogger()
# ensure we havent already registered the handler
if SentryHandler not in map(lambda x: x.__class__, logger.handlers):
    logger.addHandler(SentryHandler())
# Add StreamHandler to sentry's default so you can catch missed exceptions
logger = logging.getLogger('sentry.errors')
logger.propagate = False
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

logger call:

```
logger.warning("Category is not an integer", exc_info=sys.exc_info(), extra={'url': request.build_absolute_uri()})
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: any updates on this? I have a similar issue, except Sentry logging works fine on my dev server but not my production server. My production has the exact same symptoms listed above.

Comment: Where you get logger to save warning and when adding Sentry handler is executed? Because it can be not executed on production if you use it in manage.py, for example.

Comment: I add the Sentry logger right before I log the warning, so I'm sure it's getting executed. I don't know why it would work on my dev server and not my production server, though.

Comment: I'm very interested in that answer too.

Answer (score 4):

You're attaching the sentry stream handler to `logging.getLogger('sentry.errors')`. That means that logs to sentry.errors or below that will use that sentry stream handler.

But logs to `'my_app.something'` don't end up there! So you're missing almost all log messages.

Solution: attach the stream handler to the root logger: `logging.getLogger('')`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add:

> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

after the logging.getlogger, it works for me on dev env.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that did not work for me. 404s and 500s, as well as other exceptions, are recorded just fine though... any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: A little update. Not only did that not work, that line of code actually kills my Django dev server. When I comment it out, things work fine again. Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can add FileHandler to 'sentry.errors' logger and the check if it contains some error on production. But really stdout should be wrote to server logs. Can check this.